# regex get value

Tags: regex

Ey stackoverflow, I got this href:

```
<a href="/view?view=1"></a>
```

I am looking for a regexp that gets the first href content where href starts with /view. How am I supposed to do it ? Been looking everywhere.

Comment: **1.** [Don't parse HTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2812842) **2.** using XPath or similar would be a much better idea

Comment: Try a `dom parser` instead in the language you're using

Comment: `var regex = /^<a href="(\/view\?view=1)"><\/a>$/;
"<a href=\"/view?view=1\"></a>".match(regex)[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by others in comments, **don't use regex to parse HTML**, use a proper parser. Check: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

```
$ echo '<a href="/view?view=1"></a>' |
    xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//a/@href[starts-with(., "/view")]' -
```

or

```
$ echo '<a href="/view?view=1"></a>' |
    saxon-lint --xpath 'string(//a/@href[starts-with(., "/view")])' -
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
/view?view=1
```

#### Check [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) or [saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint)